# C# similar bitwise operations resulting in different answers

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm currently writing a solution to a project in my CS class, and I'm getting conflicting results.

Basically, I have to read a single BIT from a BYTE that is read from a file.

These are the relevant methods (ignore the naming standards, I didn't make them and I hate them too):

```
static bool no_more_bytes()
/**********************/
/*** NO MORE BYTES? ***/
/**********************/
{
    return (in_stream.PeekChar() == -1);
}

static byte read_a_byte()
/********************************************************************************/
/*** Function to read a single byte from the input stream and set end_of_file ***/
/********************************************************************************/
{
    byte abyte;

    if (!no_more_bytes())
        abyte = in_stream.ReadByte();
    else
    {
        abyte = 0;
        end_of_file = true;
    }

    return abyte;
}

static byte getbit()
/**********************************************************/
/*** Function to get a single BIT from the input stream ***/
/**********************************************************/
{
    byte mask;

    if (current_byte == 0 || current_bit_position == 8)
    {
        current_byte = read_a_byte();
        current_bit_position = 0;
    }

    mask = current_bit_position;
    current_bit_position++;

    //Your job is to fill in this function so it returns
    //either a zero or a one for each bit in the file. 

    bool set = (current_byte & (128 >> current_bit_position - 1)) != 0; // This is the line in question
    if (set)
    {
        return 1;
    } else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

getbit() is the method I wrote, and it works properly. However, my first solution didn't work.

When the input file contains "ABC", it correctly outputs `01000001 00100001 01100001` (65, 66, 67) by reading 1 bit at a time.

However, my original solution was

```
bool set = (current_byte & (1 << current_bit_position - 1)) != 0;
```

So the question is: why does shifting 128 right by the current_bit_position get a different result than shifting 1 left by the current_bit_position

Comment: Just print out that intermediate value for each of the two cases to see what the difference is.

Comment: Assume `current_bit_position` is 3.  `128 >> 2` would be `00100000`, while `1 << 2` is `00000100`.  You'd need a different calculation on the offset.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why should those two things be the same?  Suppose the current bit position is 1. Why should 128 shifted by 0 be the same as 1 shifted by 0?  You seem to have some idea that two things that are never equal should always be equal, but you have not given any justification for that false belief, so we are unable to point out to you why you believe a false thing.

Comment: My advice to you is that you write a helper method like this: `static bool BitIsSet(byte value, int bit) { if (bit < 0 || bit > 7) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bit"); return *you fill in this logic here*;}` and now you have a method that does *one thing* that you can exhaustively test by writing 256 x 8 test cases and running all of them. Once you have that, then you have something that you *know* works and you can use with confidence.

Comment: Other things that will help you write correct code: (1) `set` as a variable name is legal but considered weird by many, including me. Try to avoid using contextual keywords as identifiers. `isSet` would be better. (2) avoid global state -- make methods whose outputs depend solely on their inputs. They're much easier to understand, and much easier to test.

Comment: And of course you are correct that whoever is teaching you to use `snake_casing` in a C# program is doing it wrong, and this is correlated with other bad practices. Consider finding a teacher who teaches you good practices, rather than teaching you bad habits that you'll have to break later.

Comment: Also, it is very error-prone for you to represent bit positions from 1 to 8, and then have to remember to subtract off one.  Represent bit positions from 0 to 7, and then you don't have to remember to subtract. We're used to thinking of the lowest bit as being the zero bit, and it is easy to remember, because two-to-the-zero is one, which is the value of the zero bit when it is on.

Comment: @JamesThorpe that's the explanation that helped the best. I didn't even think about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to interpret this question as one about the order of the bits because, as comments suggest, it doesn't make much sense to expect different operations on the same data to return the same result, in most cases.

So why are we starting with 128 and shifting right instead of starting with 1 and shifting left? Both methods would be valid for enumerating through each bit within the byte, but they operate in reverse order.

If you want to shift `1` left (`<<`) instead of shifting `128` right (`>>`) you would have to run `current_bit_position` from 7 to 0 instead of from 0 to 7.

## Shifting 1

- 1 << 7 == 10000000
- 1 << 6 == 01000000
- 1 << 5 == 00100000
- 1 << 4 == 00010000
- 1 << 3 == 00001000
- 1 << 2 == 00000100
- 1 << 1 == 00000010
- 1 << 0 == 00000001

## Shifting 128

- 128 >> 0 == 10000000
- 128 >> 1 == 01000000
- 128 >> 2 == 00100000
- 128 >> 3 == 00010000
- 128 >> 4 == 00001000
- 128 >> 5 == 00000100
- 128 >> 6 == 00000010
- 128 >> 7 == 00000001

Since we generally represent numbers with the most significant digits on the left and the least significant on the right the above sequences are what you would need to use to get the bits in the right order.

Comment: This and James Thorpe's comment helped me to understand that. I wasn't even taking into account the actual position.